# No puedo listar los registros de mi BD

Tags: php, pdo, fpdf

Estoy comenzando a utilizar la librería FPDF y necesito generar un documento PDF con los registros de mi tabla "triunfadores". Hasta el momento pude generar el documento PDF pero no he podido listar los registros de mi tabla, agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Sé que en mi consulta lo que pido es que me devuelva todos los registros, anteriormente lo hacía con los campos "id" y "nombre_triun", lo coloqué así porque ya no se me ocurren más ideas y estuve probando bastantes formas de solucionar esto pero nada, así que dejé el código tal cual estaba al momento de terminar una de las muchas pruebas que lleve a cabo:

```
<?php 

    include('fpdf/fpdf.php');<br>
    include('conexion-modelo.php');

    class Conectar extends Conexion{
        public $pdoSTMT;

        public function __construct(){
            Conexion::realizandoConexion();
        }

        public function querySQL(){
            $stmt = Conexion::query("SELECT * FROM triunfadores");
            return $stmt;
        }
    }

    class PDF extends FPDF{
        function header(){
            $this->Cell(5,5,'id','C');
            $this->Cell(5,5,'nombre_triun','C');
        }
    }

    $obj = new Conectar();
    $pdf = new PDF();

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $datos = $obj -> querySQL(); 

    while($row = $datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $row["id"];
    }

    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: No conozco esa librería, pero la lectura de los datos la estás haciendo mal. Cambia el `while`  por algo como esto: **`$rows = $datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  foreach ($rows as $row){
    echo $row["id"]." - ".$row["nombre_triun"].PHP_EOL;}`**

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte del código:

```
while($row = $datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row["id"];
}
```

Estás haciendo un `echo $row["id"]`... pero con FPDF no se escribe en el archivo PDF poniendo `echo` se escribe con funciones como [`Text`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/text.htm), [`Write`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/write.htm) o [`Cell`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm) (que ya usas en otra parte de tu código). Usar `echo` también podría darte otros problemas adicionales (p.e. el famoso error de "las cabeceras ya se han enviado").

Entonces, en lugar de usar `echo` deberías utilizar alguna de las funciones especificadas arriba. En el ejemplo pongo `Cell` porque ya la estás usando para las cabeceras:

> Aviso: no he probado este código y podría contener errores

```
while($row = $datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $pdf->Cell(5,5,$row["id"],'C');
}
```